# How to make a prediction with a trained model that is using a feature layer?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a trained model that uses a feature layer for its inputs.
I am happy with the training and performance of the model on the validation and test sets.

But now, I want to create manually a new example to send to the model and get a prediction out of it.

My code looks like the following:

...

```
categorical_columns = []
numeric_columns = []

# numeric cols
for header in ['CreditScore', 'Age', 'Tenure', 'Balance', 'NumOfProducts', 'HasCrCard','IsActiveMember','EstimatedSalary']:
  numeric_columns.append(feature_column.numeric_column(header))

# categorical cols
categories = {
                'Geography':['France', 'Spain', 'Germany'],
                'Gender': ['Female', 'Male']
             }

for header, possible_values in categories.items():
  cat_col = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(key=header, vocabulary_list=possible_values)
  categorical_columns.append(tf.feature_column.indicator_column(cat_col))

feature_columns =  numeric_columns + categorical_columns

feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_layer,
  layers.Dense(6, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(6, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'],
              run_eagerly=True)

history = model.fit(x=train_ds, validation_data=val_ds, epochs=4)
```

Not worrying about feature scaling for this question, how would I send this data to the model and get a prediction out of it?
What syntax should I use?

- CreditScore:  358
- Age:  42
- Tenure:   5
- Balance:  4000
- NumOfProducts:    5
- HasCrCard 1:
- IsActiveMember:   1
- EstimatedSalary:  50000
- Geography:    France
- Gender:   Male

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Exactly the same format you have in `train_ds`.